# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-5.6

I was trying to install MySQL 5.6.15 to my computer and got this error:

> unable to update security settings. access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)

I guess current root password is wrong but I do not remember what it was. So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome do dba.SE! This guide on how to format posts may be of interest. (You can find it by clicking the question mark top right while editing.)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed MySQL 5.6 from the command line, the easiest way to find the temporary password is to go to the Linux command line do the following:

```
cd
cat `ls -la | grep mysql | grep secret | awk '{print $9}'` | awk '{print $18}'
```

This will quickly print the temporary password.

Try to login using that password

```
cd
OLDPASSFILE=`ls -la | grep mysql | grep secret | awk '{print $9}'`
PASSWORD=`cat ${OLDPASSFILE} | awk '{print $18}'
mysql -uroot -p${PASSWORD}
```

If the temporary password is no longer available, then you will have do the following:

```
NEWPASS="whateveriwant"
service mysql stop
service mysql start --skip-grant-tables
mysql -ANe"update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('${NEWPASS}') where user='root'"
service mysql restart
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929831/unable-to-update-security-settings-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-u :

> The prior install screen had asked for the Current root password. But this was the first MySQL install on the machine.
>
> Answer: when asked for the Current root password, leave that field blank. Then the server installed ok.

Comment: I left that current root password field blank but only the error changed. "Unable to update security settings. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

Comment: It means you have to remove mysql and installed it again

Comment: In that case you'll have to reset your existing password using one of the many answers for that on here, or perhaps just wipe your MySQL data directory on this machine if you don't need it.

Comment: No need to reinstall. See Rolando's comment below re: "skip-grant-tables."