# DBeaver: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0, dbeaver

Context: I am creating a new Schema and looking to import .sql file generated from mysql dump. I have server running: MySQL 8.0.19.

I am using DBeaver client Version 7.0.2 and have setup a new MySQL 8+ Database connection. However, when I attempt to connect to the DB, I run into the following error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

A root user exist (verified through mysql shell). Here are a few things I have attempted, however, haven't been able to resolve the issue yet:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to login as root?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55559/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Comment: @Colin'tHart, I'm not op but I tried logging in as root because you can do that in Postgres. I've dabbled with MySQL/MariaDB but I guess I forgot its best to make a new user?

Comment: @DeltaFlyer Don’t run your program as root if you can run it as a normal non-privileged user.

Answer (score 2):

Create new user with password and full privileges as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131286/problem-in-accessing-to-mysql):

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'the_password_you_wish_here';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

...and login with this user for further usages.

Comment: Please add some details to the answer, as link-only answers can become obsolete. Thanks.